# Why won't child components rerender without using getDerivedStateFromProps?

Tags: reactjs

I cannot figure out why when my selectedEvent successfully changes via setState that my child components do not re-render with the updated state. In the child if I use getDerivedStateFromProps() I can get itto work, but I don't think that should be necessary. I'm missing something.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         selectedEvent: '',
         eventsData: EventsData,
         langData: LangData,
      }

      this.changeStoryEvent = this.changeStoryEvent.bind(this);

   };

   changeStoryEvent(event) {
      let newEvent = event.target.getAttribute('data-event-key');
      if(newEvent != null) {
         console.log("new event", newEvent)
         this.setState({ 
            selectedEvent: newEvent
         })      
      }
   }


   render() {
      console.log("select", this.state.selectedEvent)
      return (
         <div>
               <div className="header">
                  <Header />
               </div>
               <div className="sidebar">
                  <Sidebar 
                     changeEvent={this.changeStoryEvent} 
                     eventsData={this.state.eventsData}
                     selectedEvent={this.state.selectedEvent}
                  />
               </div>
               <div className="mainbar">
                  app event = {this.state.selectedEvent} <br />
                  <Mainbar 
                     selectedEvent={this.state.selectedEvent}
                     eventsData={this.state.eventsData}
                     langData={this.state.langData}
                  />
               </div>

         </div>
      )
   }
}


class Mainbar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super()

        this.state = {
            selectedEvent: props.selectedEvent,
            changeEventType: props.changeEventType,
            eventsData: props.eventsData,
            langData: props.langData
        }

        this.changeEventType = this.changeEventType.bind(this)
    }

    changeEventType(event) {

    }   

    render() {
        console.log('mainstate', this.state)

        let eventType = '';
        if (this.state.selectedEvent !== '') {
            eventType = this.state.eventsData[this.state.selectedEvent].type
        }
        if (eventType === '') {
            eventType = 'action'
        }


        return (
            <div className="mainbar">
                mainevent = {this.state.selectedEvent}
                <StoryEvent
                    eventType={eventType}
                    selectedEvent={this.state.selectedEvent}
                    changeEventType={this.changeEventType}
                    eventsData={this.state.eventsData}
                    langData={this.state.langData}
                />
                {this.state.langData.events[this.state.selectedEvent]}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

I see the selectedEvent correctly updated in class App, but not in Mainbar. It apparently does not receive the updated state of selectedEvent.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you share the code of your `StoryEvent` component?

Answer (score 0):

in you child component, you are copying selectedEvent from props to state, then using this.state.selectedEvent in render.

The constructor is only called once, so you won't update the state of you child later on when the prop change.

Use directly this.props.selectedEvent in the render method